# Why is the last element repeating?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the diagonal and counter diagonal elements for a given list. The function is written below:

```py
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    side_1=0
    side_2 =0

    for row in arr:
        for column in row:
            if(arr.index(row)==row.index(column)):
                side_1+=column
            if(arr.index(row)+row.index(column)==(len(arr)-1)):
                print(arr.index(row),row.index(column)) #(1)index for counter diagonal
                side_2+=column 

    return(abs(side_1-side_2))
```

Edit: The values passed are:
(-1 1 -7 -8),
(-10 -8 -5 -2),
(0 9 7 -1),
(4 4 -2 1)

The result of (1) is:
(0,3),
(1,2),
(2,1),
(3,0),
(3,0)

The repeated values 4, 4 in the position [3][0],[3][1] is generating the problem

Comment: Can you describe a little more what you want to achieve with your code? What should be the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, with repeating values, your index lookup fails. You are also iterating over the every value instead of just the ones you want (the diagonals). Rather than taking the entries of the list and then finding their index (with `index` method), just use the indices to start with.

```
>>> a = ((-1, 1, -7, -8), (-10, -8, -5, -2), (0, 9, 7, -1), (4, 4 ,-2, 1))
>>> d1 = d2 = 0
>>> dim = len(a)
>>> for i in range(dim): 
...     d1 += a[i][i] 
...     d2 += a[i][dim-i-1]
...
>>> print(d1, d2)
-1 0
```

You may want some validation that all the lists are the same length and that the array is square, but if you can assume that, this should be ok.

Comment: yes, common entries were the problem. I just didn't understand how python interprets repeating values as belonging to the same index.

Comment: It doesn't treat them as belonging to the same index. It's more that the `index` method returns the index of the first element that is equal to the given object. When two objects are equal, `index` will return the same value for them.